# What is the meaning of the word "treat" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

In an RPG video game I'm playing I'm trying to gain access to a medical clinic but a receptionist that works there doesn't want to let me in. One of the dialog options to convince her is:

"I'm just bringing my friend who's been **treated some personal items**."

I know that the noun "treat" means:

> a. To give medical aid to (someone): treated many patients in the emergency room.
> or
> b. To provide with food, entertainment, or gifts at one's own expense: treated her sister to the theater.
> or
> c. To give (someone or oneself) something pleasurable: treated herself to a day in the country.
> (source TFD)

Is it medical treatment in this case or an act of giving something? (tell me if it's possible to figure out from this context although i suspect it may be not)

Answer (score 2):

The sentence probably get's a bit clearer if we add some commata:

> I'm just bringing my friend, who's been treated, some personal items.

So the speaker is referring to a friend who has been treated in the clinic and is probably still there recuperating (from an operation or such).

Answer (score 1):

It does make sense if you reorganize the sentence:

> "I'm just bringing some personal items to my friend who's been treated."

The original sentence follows the same format as "*I'm bringing my friend some things*", while the reorganized version has the same format as, "*I'm bringing some things to my friend.*"

I couldn't understand the original sentence until I'd read it several times.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I failed to realise that the commas were the key to understanding it :) thank you for your help ;)